# "Set Up iAd Network" button doesn't appear on iTunesConnect

Tags: app-store-connect, iad

I have just submitted my new app on iTunes Connect but I didn't see the "Set Up iAd Network" to activate iAd on this app.
For my last app, the button appeared.

Is it normal ?

Thanks

Comment: Im missing it as well but strictly speaking, this question isn't suitable for Stack overflow.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about itunesconnect and not programming.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same doubt, but I found out that there´s no more need to set it up for another app. The explanation was right in front of me (us), at the homepage of iTunes Connect:

iAd App Network Configuration Update
Once you sign the iAd App Network Contract and integrate the iAd Framework in your app, all approved and Ready for Sale apps will be eligible to receive iAd ads. You no longer need to enable each app for iAd in the Manage Your Apps module.

Comment: Yes this is correct. I was having the same worries as you sir.

Comment: Thanks It was helpful, I signed the contract but looking for that button for hours.

Answer (score 3):

Vic HT is right. Heres a screenshot.

[image: iAd App Network Configuration Update Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72324/how-to-activate-iad-network-in-itunes-connect) link. You have to fill a contract.

1. Login to iTunes Connect.
2. Select the "Contracts Tax And Banking".
3. And request for iAds.
4. Accept the agreement.
5. Provide the bank info.
6. It's done